# Excel Delete row if cell contains an empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a bit of data-preprocessing. I want to write a macro that deletes any rows that contain any empty cells.

I've been looking on the internet for help but they've either gotten me nowhere or I can't quite understand the code

```
Sub ListWiseDel()


Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:U1077")
If IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

I've been trying this but i keep getting errors.

Comment: So, what error do you get? Also I am no expert, but it looks like you did not define `c` anywhere. Also you may need to use `cell` instead of `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Add .Cells after range("A1:U1077") and change "c" to cell. Also, change activecell to cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Sub delEmptyRow()

    Dim col, ligne
    Dim vide

    ligne = 10
    While ligne > 0
        vide = False
        col = 1
        Do While Not vide And col <= 10
            If IsEmpty(Cells(ligne, col)) Then
                vide = True
            End If
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        If vide Then Cells(ligne, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        ligne = ligne - 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Just adapt : replace 10 by 1077 for lines and 10 by 21 for columns

Comment: Thank you nicolas that's a great help. Can i ask what the 'vide' variable does?

Comment: sorry, french name - read "empty". When reading the row cells "vide" is set to true so that we know we can stop analysing the line because it can be removed. However I'm not sure my solution is the better, you might probably proceed with writing less code.